# Ask the user to input for file name. and in the in loop than ask the user to write and close the file. in c

Tags: c

I am trying to open a text file from user's input. In the loop ask the user to write. If the user types 0, it ends the program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

 int main(){

 char filename[50];
 FILE* fpointer;

 printf ("Please Enter the File Name: ");
 scanf ("%s",&filename);
 fpointer = fopen(filename,"r");
```

Here I need a loop to ask user to write in a file, until the user enters 0 to end the programe.

```
 if (filename == 0)
 {
    getch();
    exit(1);
}
filename(close);


}
```

Comment: `filename == 0` is equivalent to `filename == NULL`, which will never be true.

Comment: On another note, `&filename` is wrong for `scanf`. Because `filename` is an array, the type of `&filename` is a pointer to the array itself, `char (*)[50]`. This is not the type expected by the `%s` format, which expects a `char *`. Which you get from `&filename[0]` or just plainly `filename`. Mismatching format and argument type leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: As for your problem, `filename` is a string. If you want to check if the user inputted a zero, you need to compare to the string `"0"` (which you can't do using `==`).

Comment: Perhaps `filename(close);` should be `fclose(fpointer);`

Comment: Or do you mean that you want to read input from the user separate from the file? Then you need to read actual input from the user and compare it to the correct value. And to be honest, it seems like you're just guessing around without really knowing anything. Perhaps you need to take a few steps backs, and start over with a decent book (or class) and the basic "hello world" type program?

Answer (score 0):

You probably wanted this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char filename[50];
    FILE *fp;
    int check = 1;
    
    while(check)
    {
        printf("Enter name of the file or path: ");
        scanf("%50s", filename);
        if(!(fp = fopen(filename, "r")))
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Can't open the file.\n");
            exit(-1);
        }
        // file reading statements...
        fclose(filename);
        printf("Do you want to continue(1 to continue/0 to exit): ");
        scanf(" %d", &check);
    }
}
```

Here we are declaring an `int` variable `check` to exit the loop. Inside `while` loop if value of `check` is updated in the last `scanf` then it will cause the exit from the loop, else we'll continue asking for `filename` and following statements will be executed over and over again.

And yeah please read comments on your question.